# Can you make reusable your UI functions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface

A simple example is a function I want to create.

```
private void drawRectangle(int x, int y)
```

I send coordinates and it draws a rectangle with some particularities. That function will be in at least two forms. What do you do to make that function reusable and prevent from writing it in two places?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WinForms, pass the Graphics object to your method:

```
private void drawRectangle(int x, int y, Graphics g)
```

Then draw the rectangle to the Graphics object.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a third parameter, eg `UIElement` so that your method looks like this:

```
private void drawRectangle(int x, int y, UIElement space)
```

and let the method print the Rectangle on the specified space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is UIElement working on winforms? I thought it only worked for WPF?

Comment: @Mathieu, of course you didn't specify WinForms in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Add another class to your project, add this method as a *public* static helper function.  You'll need to provide more arguments, at least a Graphics object I imagine.  A rectangle is also going to need a width and height.  Avoid hard-coding these, it is rarely appropriate when your form gets rescaled on a machine with a higher video DPI setting.

Comment: Thank you for the good practice advice! Especially about rescaling, something I tend to forget all the time.